# Invalid Identifier When Specifying Columns During Pivot - ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle12c

When trying to create a pivot, I get a `ORA-00904 invalid identifier` error on the following query.

Table Definition

```
create table table1(id int, name varchar2(20), col1 int);
insert into table1 values(1, 'Alex', 99);
insert into table1 values(2, 'Alex', 98);
insert into table1 values(3, 'James', 97);
insert into table1 values(4, 'Eric', 99);
insert into table1 values(5, 'Stan', 99);
```

Error Query

```
select name, col1
from table1
pivot (count(name) for col1 in (99, 98, 97))
;
```

However, the following queries will work

Working Query 1

```
select *
from table1
pivot (count(name) for col1 in (99, 98, 97)) p
;
```

Working Query 2

```
with cte as (
  select name, col1
  from table1
)
select *
from cte
pivot (count(name) for col1 in (99, 98, 97))
;
```

I prefer the output of Working Query 2 as I get the counts without all the other data included

```
    99 | 98 | 97
-------|----|-------
    3  |  1 | 1
```

Why does the error occur when attempting to pivot when specifying the columns directly from the table?

[SQL Fiddle Example - Error is on 3rd query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74073/12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `pivot`, `name` is no longer in the result set.  It has been replaced by the count and columns with names like "99".

That is why one often uses `select *` with `pivot`.  Most of the columns have already been listed in the `in` clause.